# 2002 - Network is unreachable - The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: linux, mysql, socket, phpmyadmin

I can't login to PHPMyAdmin getting error as **#2002 - Network is unreachabl**, I installed PHPMyAdmin from source.

Configuration I tried in **config.inc.php** to fix the issue.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0 0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

Another fix I Tried is to set **mysql.default_socket** to **/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock**
 but I didn't find one In my php.ini file I find **pro_mysql.default_socke** and not mysql.default_socket, Do I need to add the mysql.sock path to pro_mysql.default_socke

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're asking phpMyAdmin to connect by TCP but your database is listening to an UNIX socket.  Remove the `connect_type` line and set `host` to `localhost`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

Comment: Its not working getting the same error, I had the default setting as localhost to fix this issue I tried with 127.0 0.1

Comment: Use `127.0.0.1` for TCP connections.  Use `localhost` for UNIX domain sockets.  Make sure your web server doesn't run chrooted to use UNIX domain sockets.  Don't mess with the default socket values in `my.cnf` and `php.ini` if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I haven't done any configuration with chrooted to use UNIX domain sockets. If so How can I check. I really don't know what it means :(